# Rails Route Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a series of items I would wish to edit. When editing the current format of my URL appears as such:

```
http://mysite/items <---- Lists the items
http://mysite/items/1/ <------ more detailed view of items
http://mysite/items/1/edit <----- Ability to edit the item
```

The routing configuration I would like to try and apply to my structure would like something like this:

```
http://mysite/items <---- Lists the items
http://mysite/item <---- Detailed view of the item by sending the item ID as POST data
http://mysite/item/edit <---- Edits the item by sending the item ID as POST data
```

Is this strictly an event of the rails route configuration or do I have to configure the links in the `items` page to structure the URL specifically.

Comment: Just my opinion, if you set URL like `http://mysite/item`, how do you know which ID of item you will show?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#config/routes.rb
#assuming your actions are in ItemsController
match 'items' => 'items#index', :via => :get
match 'item' => 'items#show', :via => :post
match 'item/edit' => 'items#edit', :via => :post
```

Be aware this is more for legacy applications/URLs as Rails convention follows RESTful mapping. Further info in [the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).